# reading a nibble from file in verilog

Tags: file-io, verilog

I need to read data from a file nibble by nibble (half byte) in verilog. I know I can read 8 bits using character but is there anyway of reading nibble?
The code I use for character reading is

```
reg [7:0] char1;
integer read_file;

initial begin
    read_file = $fopen("D:\\signal.txt","rb");

    char1 = $fgetc(read_file);       // read a byte
end
```

is there anything else for reading nibble?

Comment: Just read in the byte, then split it into 2 nibbles.

Answer (score -1):

consider $fread.

```
reg [3:0] data;
integer rtn_val;
... 
rtn_val = $fread(data, read_file);
```

Comment: This won't work for multiple nibbles.  It loads a nibble into `data`, but it discards the next nibble.  According to IEEE Std 1800, `$fread` : `The data in the file shall be read byte by byte ... If the memory width is not evenly divisible by 8, not all data in the file are loaded into memory because of truncation.`